# how to add custom amount to shipping & handling in cart

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, totals

How to add custom amount to shipping & handling  in cart on Magento 1.9?
Here I did it but shipping charge was added two times to grand total.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
class modelname_Model_Sales_Total_Quote_Ccfee extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setCode('ccfee');
    }

    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        parent::collect($address);
         $shipping_charge = $this->calculateCustomTax($address);         
           if ($shipping_charge){                           
                $address->setShippingAmount($shipping_charge);
                $address->setBaseShippingAmount($shipping_charge); 
           }                    
            $address->setGrandTotal($address->getGrandTotal() + $address->getShippingAmount());                       
            return $this;
    }
    protected function calculateCustomTax()
    {
              $shipping_charge = 0;
              $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
                foreach ($cart as $item){
                $options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());                    
                $select_ship[] = $options['info_buyRequest']['select_ship'];
                }           
                $ship = $select_ship;

           if($ship != 0)
           {
                $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
                foreach ($cart as $item)
                {
                    $options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
                    $select_ship[] = $options['info_buyRequest']['select_ship'];
                }
                $shipping_charge = $select_ship;
            }           

            else{
                    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
                    foreach ($cart as $item)
                    {
                      $options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());                  
                      $select_ship[] = $options['info_buyRequest']['select_ship'];
                    }
                 $shipping_charge = max($select_ship); 
               }               
            return  $shipping_charge;

        }
```

Comment: Are you looking to change the shipping amount dynamic. Or want to add 1 more charge same like shipping & handling ?

Comment: How about your current issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your logic, however, basically, we have two types of quote address: `shipping` and `billing`. We don't need to calculate for billing address. So, we need to check the type of address.

```
    parent::collect($address);
    $quote = $address->getQuote();
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore($quote->getStoreId());
    $this->_calculator->reset($address);

    $items = $this->_getAddressItems($address);
    if (!count($items)) {
        return $this;
    }
```

There is a good example [here](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/).